# Hosting Projects at On-Premise Servers

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx

My project ABC is ready with the following specs required to host it.

```
            • Nginx (with HTTP/2 enabled) 1.18
```

I have a friend who has an on premise platform with IIS and MSSQL server pre installed. My C# projects are being hosted in that platform.

I am wondering if my new Project ABC can be hosted in the same on premise platform if all the above software are installed.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a friend who has an on premise platform with IIS and MSSQL
> server pre installed. My C# projects are being hosted in that
> platform.

This lead me to believe the on-premise server you use are Windows-based. This can cause some trouble if you want to deploy the stack you mentioned.

Parts of the stack you want to deploy are native to Linux, which lead to many hops to jump through if you do not want/have another layer of virtualization.

Nginx and Redis are the two on top of my mind